# Navigation Bar highlights on current page or text decoration

Tags: highlight, navbar, navigationbar

here is my code sir.

http://cssdesk.com/9cWbV

which should I take out or should I add I wanted it to display a text decoration when it is on the current page any advice or tips I'm noob I feel my code is rather messy

or it's best if you can advice me on highlight it on current page

I'm noob so dont flame me soo much :/

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the navigation item and apply CSS for that class.

```
<li class="active"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>

ul#navbar li.active a {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

Use PHP to add that class

```
define("THIS_PAGE", "home");

<li if(THIS_PAGE=="home"){ echo 'class="active"'; }>
  <a href="home.php">Home</a>
</li>
```

Comment: add `define("THIS_PAGE", "home");` to the top of the home page and add `if(THIS_PAGE=="home"){ echo 'class="active"'; }` to your navigation `<li>`